generality and specificity in Numbers 1:1
The very beginning of Bamidbar reads:

וידבר ה׳ אל משה
במדבר סיני באהל מועד
באחד לחדש השני בשנה השנית לצאתם מארץ מצרים
לאמר


God spoke to Moses
in the Sinai desert, in the designation tent,
on the first of the second month, in the second year from the Egyptian exodus,
saying:

When describing where the communication took place, this verse goes from general (the Sinai desert) to specific (the tent).  When describing when the communication to place, it goes from specific (the day of the year) to general (the year).
Why?
(And if you'll show me that that's a general feature of descriptions of place and time in the Pentateuch, not specific to this verse, then my question is more general: why do where-descriptions go from general to specific and when-descriptions from specific to general?)

The Or HaChaim asks your question and explains that the entire world, including the desert, is under the dominion of Hashem, Who dwelt within the Tent. In that sense, the second location descriptor is the more general one, so both place and time are described from the specific to the general.
